# Parameters as array in Yaml in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, yaml

I'm doing this which works fine:

```
parameters:
 array_name1: [a, b, c, d]
 array_name2: [x, y, a, b]
```

Now I need to add what in PHP would be $array_name3[1] = array("a", "b", "c") etc., so something like this:

```
parameters:
 array_name3[1]: [1, 2, 3]
 array_name3[2]: [a, b, c]
 array_name3[3]: [x, y, z]
```

...which of course doesn't work. Nothing I try seems to be accepted.

How do I define multi-dimensional arrays in Yaml (Symfony2)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this

```
parameters:
   array_name3: 
      - [1, 2, 3]
      - [a, b, c]
      - [x, y, z]
```

Or if you want to have it associative:

```
parameters:
   array_name3: 
      1: [1, 2, 3]
      2: [a, b, c]
      bla: [x, y, z]
```

Or if you want more - [read documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#collections)