# Symfony2, How to pass array as parameter to controller action?

Tags: symfony, routes

How to pass array as parameter to controller action using Symfony 2? Could you please write an example how to define route, which contains unknown length array as a parameter. For instance url: http://localhost:8000/blog/post/?tags=[tag1,tag2,tag3] where number of tags varies from 0 to 100. 
Also example controller for this route, where action returns values of tags array.

Using the following coding (see routing.yml and controller.php below) i am getting the error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Component\Routing\Route::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\dctr\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php on line 147 and defined in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\dctr\app/config\routing.yml (which is being imported from "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\dctr\app/config/routing_dev.yml").
```

url:

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/post/tag1
http://localhost:8000/blog/post/tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4
http://localhost:8000/blog/post/?tags=[tag1,tag2]
```

Below are different combinations of routing and controller files i have tried so far:

//version r1, routing.yml

```
blog_post_tags:
    path: blog/post/{tags}
    defaults: { _controller: DefaultController:list_postsByTagActionQ }
    requirements:
        tags : "[a-zA-Z0-9,]+"
```

//version r2, routing.yml

```
blog_post_tags:
    resource: "@BlogBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /blog/
    defaults: { _controller: DefaultController:list_postsByTagActionQ }
```

//version r1,2-c1  , controller.php

```
//http://localhost:8000/blog/post/?tags=[tag1,tag2] .
/**
 * @Route("/posts/{tags}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function list_postsByTagAction($tags){
    var_dump($tags);
    return array('posts'=>['post1','post2']);
}
```

//version r1,2-c2   , controller.php

```
//url http://localhost:8000/blog/post/?tags=[tag1,tag2]
/**
 * @Route("/posts/{tags}")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function list_postsByTagActionQ1(Request $request){
    $tags=$request->query->get('tags'); // get a $_GET parameter       
    var_dump($tags);
    return array('posts'=>['post1','post2']);
}
```

//version r1,2-c3  , controller.php

```
//url http://localhost:8000/blog/post/?tags=[tag1,tag2]
/**
 * @Route("/posts/{tags}")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function list_postsByTagActionQ3(Request $request, $tags){           
    var_dump($tags);
    return array('posts'=>['post1','post2']);
}
```

//version r3, routing.yml

```
blog_post_tags:
    path: blog/post/{tags}
    defaults: { _controller: DefaultController:list_postsByTagActionQ }
```

//version r3-c4  , controller.php

```
//url http://localhost:8000/blog/post/?tags=[tag1,tag2]
 public function list_postsByTagActionQ(Request $request){
    $tags=$request->query->get('tags'); // get a $_GET parameter
      var_dump($tags);
}
```

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15545813/5397119

Comment: I need example with routing.yml and controller.php

Comment: values, not parameters in my question forms an array

Answer (score 3):

Well, after some tries I've found next solution.

You can change your pattern in routing to this (tags : **"[a-zA-Z0-9/]+"**):

```
blog_post_tag:
    path: blog/post/{tags}
    defaults: { _controller: DefaultController:list_postsByTagActionQ }
    requirements:
        tags : "[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+"
```

Then you can pass http://localhost:8000/blog/post/tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4, but you still need explode() for getting parameters.

Comment: i have removed requirements at all, but i am getting the same error.

Comment: Is your file saved in utf-8? maybe you have invisible char after "requirements" key.. like line-break? try to remove requirements and write it again from scratch.

Comment: version r2 and version r3 has no requirements

Comment: @olga so, you always get error "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Component\Routing\Route::__construct()..." ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i found an answer. Instead of passing an array, better encode it to a json string. Here is kind of example:

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\src\MeetingBundle\Controller\UserController.php

```
..
    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, User $user)
    {
..
 $bredArr=array( 'user_edit' => array (  'id'=>$user->getId() ) );
..
        return $this->render( 'MeetingBundle::user/edit.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'image_form' => $imageForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
            'bredArr'=>$bredArr,
        ));
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\src\MeetingBundle\Controller\ImageController.php
..

```
   /**
     * Deletes a Image entity without displaying forms. nf = no forms
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/deletenf/{bredArrJ}", name="image_deletenf")
     * @Method("GET|POST")
     */    
     public function deletenfAction(Request $request, $id, $bredArrJ) 
     {

        $bredArr=json_decode($bredArrJ, $assoc = true);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('MeetingBundle:Image')->find($id);
            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Image entity.');
            }
            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();  

            if(array_key_exists('image_delete', $bredArr)) {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('image_index'));
            }
            else if (array_key_exists('user_edit', $bredArr)){
                return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('user_edit', array( 'id'=>$bredArr['user_edit']['id'] ) ) );
            }     
            else if {
                //redirect to other pages according key in $bredArr
            }
     }
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\src\MeetingBundle\Resources\views\user\edit.html.twig

```
{# dispplays user, user_delete and image uplaod forms, also shows images which belongs to user, retrieving them via ManyToMany realation in User entity field "imgsuni" #}
 {% for img in user.imgsuni %}
 <br> {% include 'MeetingBundle:user:userimg.html.twig' %}
 {% endfor %}
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\src\MeetingBundle\Resources\views\user\userimg.html.twig

```
<img src="{{ asset( 'bundles/meeting/images/uploads/'~img.path~'' ) }}" height="100" />
<br><a href="{{  path('image_deletenf', { 'id': img.id,  'bredArrJ' : bredArr|json_encode }) }}"> Delete image </a>
"{{ img.title }}".
```

$bredArr is variable created in `User` controller `edit_user` action. It is used as an argument in path variable `image_deletenf`. I do not know how to pass it as array, but it works if encoded as Json string. I need `image_deletenf` action, in order to be able to redirect to paths where i want. I can delete images from user, event and comment entities, thus after deletion i would like to come back to user, event or comment instead of default image_index, thus i need this `$bredArr` to direct to correct entity with correct parameters.